# aggregate some kind of data with MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

First, I ask your understanding for my poor English.

I am developing mobile app server with node.js and mongoDB.
But I am stuck in processing some structure of data.
For example,

```
[{
  type: 'blah',
  createdAt: '2014-12-01'
}, {
  type: 'blah',
  createdAt: '2014-11-30'
}, {
  type: 'alah',
  createdAt: '2014-11-29'
}, {
  type: 'blah',
  createdAt: '2014-11-28'
}, {
  type: 'blah',
  createdAt: '2014-11-27'
}]
```

the data is like above.

I want to aggregate them as below

```
[{
  _id: {
    type: 'blah'
  },
  count: 2
}, {
  _id: {
    type: 'alah'
  },
  count: 1
}, {
  _id: {
    type: 'blah'
  },
  count: 2
}]
```

Of course, if I load the data ordered by "createdAt" and merge them, I will also get same result as shown above.

But I want to know whether there is another beautiful way or not.

Let me know some magic please.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

I think there is some ambiguity so, I have added some explanation.

two "type: 'blah'"s at the top is consecutive with date 'createdAt'.
And "type: 'alah'" appears and another two consecutive "type: 'blah'"s.

So, if you make group by same "type" and consecutive "createdAt",

*group1: {type: 'blah'} X 2,*

*group2: {type: 'alah'} X 1,*

*group3: {type: 'blah'} X 2*

more exactly, I wrote the wanted output at the second code block above.

I'm sorry for limitation of expression because I'm not a native.

I hope you'll understand additional explanation.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this real data or createdAt should be another ? For this data I can not find regularity...

Comment: createdAt should be a date for created date or updated date. I think createdAt is substitute with any data that can be orderable. I also added some edit. I hope it will help you with understanding my intension.

Comment: Why we should get group1: {type: 'blah'} X 2, ? in this case type: 'blah', has different createdAt ?

Comment: {type: 'blah'}s in group1 are consecutive in terms of "createdAt". If you order the data by "createdAt", two {type: 'blah'}s are consecutive and {type: 'alah'} in the middle splits {type: 'blah'}s. I want to gather them and group them by consecutive same type when ordering the data by "createdAt".

Comment: Calculating "runs" in some order is not possible with the aggregation pipeline as of 2.6. I think you'll want to process client side.